# Opening mat-expansion panel is also creating blank space in opposite panel

Tags: css, angular, mat-expansion-panel

When I am expanding any one panel then same opposite panel is also taking blank space equal to expanded panel. I have arrange two panel in a row.

I am expecting it should not create blank space on opposite panel and expand only clicked panel.